# How do you take a break from languages with minimum memory loss or detriment?

Tags: multiple-languages, learning-break

I'm a Sixth Form student in the UK. At the start of July, I have work experience. In mid-July, I have exams. In August, I have coursework and university preparation stuff. All of this is severely going to limit the time I have to study languages. This is a big worry to me because I felt like I'd been making such great progress in the two languages I'm learning over the last two months.

A break of a few months may seem like nothing to some people, but to me... not so much. In late 2018, I committed myself to learning Korean but extenuating circumstances forced me to study on/off for a whole year. I gave up for six months after that. Then two months ago, I started Korean basically from scratch because I could barely remember a thing.

I just about have enough time to keep up with small things like Duolingo and Anki testing, but are there any other ways (regardless of how small they are) that might limit how much this break from language learning affects me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through a similar issue myself, I am teaching myself intermediate French whilst at university. The important thing to keep your interest and engage your brain in the language without doing a full-on study session is this. Immerse yourself in the language by listening to Korean podcasts, YouTubers, Netflix shows and music which you could have on in the background. Also dropping some Korean into the conversation wouldn't do any harm even if its just "good morning", "yes" and "no".

I would highly recommend getting these browser extensions on Google Chrome:

- Language Learning with Netflix
- Language Learning with Youtube

I hope this helps, and good luck with your A-Levels. Try not to worry too much.

Answer (score 1):

I completely understand your worry. In theory, I have proficiency in three languages. However, if I haven't engaged with one of them for more than I month, I find it almost impossible to have a fluent conversation with a native speaker. Therefore, I try to engage with with a bit every day. It helps me if I start the day with reading the news in all three languages.

Depending on your language level, you could listen to Korean music or watch youtube videos on the way to work/school for instance.

I wish you the very best and hope the things work out for you.